# update of ngModel inside Angular directive

Tags: arrays, angularjs, binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I am binding an object from my controller on a directive in that controller. I can update fields from the directive on ngModel, however I cant seem to add or delete items from an existing property of type Array on that ngModel. It doesnt reflect on the value assigend to ngModel on the controller.

Editing a simple (existing) property of type Number or String is possible.

Could use some guidance on this.

Comment: Can you post some code, more preferably a plunker ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could show some of your code, it would be helpful. However, from what you describe, I suspect it might be possible that you are not referencing either the array or the elements in the array correctly.

Comment: this led me to the problem. without knowing it I was overwriting the reference with the default (initial) value so changes didnt reflect.